# Public Google Cloud Pub/Sub Topics?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'd like to play around with [Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub) and processing messages in [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow). Are there any public data feeds in Pub/Sub that I can use to get started?

In the Dataflow [WordCount](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/wordcount-example#minimalwordcount) example, input is read from a file in [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), `gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt`. It seems that `dataflow-samples` is accessible to all projects, which is very convenient for getting started. Is there anything similar for Pub/Sub?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently, Google maintains this public topic **projects/pubsub-public-data/topics/taxirides-realtime** as part of a Cloud Dataflow code lab.

You can find more information on how to use it [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/cloud-dataflow-nyc-taxi-tycoon).

Additionally, you can use Dataflow with BigQuery. Google provides this comprehensive [set of public data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/).

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean public datasets in Cloud Pub/Sub? In Cloud Pub/Sub, you have topics, publishers sending messages to those topics and subscribed consumers receiving messages from those topics. Every topic belongs to a project, so as such it doesn't make sense to have a public topic, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I've updated the question with more context. I was hoping there might be some public subscription that any project could create a topic to read from.

Comment: I see. I am not aware of a public topic for Pub/Sub.